# Parent child component event handler in loop

Tags: reactjs, parent

I have created one child component and one parent component the child component gets called in from loop and event handlers also get called from prop but when i click on navlink from child component every click event is called

if first navlink is called then only handler for first navlink should be called.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
// import SearchComponent from "../Common/SearchComponent";
// import Navbar from "../Common/Navbar";
import { CompanyId } from "../../locales/global.json";
import CategoryComponent from "./CategoryComponent";

class CategoryPageComponent extends Component {
state = {
    Categories: []
};
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.Categories.length === 0) this.bindCategoryData();
}
onCategorySearch = e => {
    if (this.state.Categories.length === 0 && e === "")
    this.bindCategoryData(0);
};

bindCategoryData = () => {
    var $this = this;
    axios
    .post(
        "http://fstrumplifyml.azurewebsites.net/api/ApiCategory/GetCategories",
        {
        companyid: CompanyId,
        languageid: 1
        }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
        $this.setState({
        Categories: response.data.Data
        });
    });
};
UpdateSubCategories = (categories, categoryId) => {
    console.log(categories);
};
renderCategoryComponent = category => {
    return (
    <CategoryComponent
        Category={category}
        OnUpdateSubCategories={this.UpdateSubCategories.bind(this)}
    />
    );
};
render() {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {/* <Navbar /> */}
        <section className="space--sm">
        <div className="container">
            {/* <SearchComponent onSearch={this.onCategorySearch} /> */}
            <div className="row">
            {this.state.Categories.map(this.renderCategoryComponent)}
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
export default CategoryPageComponent;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class CategoryComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="masonry__item col-md-4 filter-computing">
        <div className="product">
          <NavLink
            to={this.props.OnUpdateSubCategories(
              this.props.Category.SubCategories,
              this.props.Category.CategoryId
            )}
          >
            <img
              alt={this.props.Category.CategoryName}
              className="ProductImage"
              src={this.props.Category.ImageUrl}
            />
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            className="block"
            to={this.props.OnUpdateSubCategories(
              this.props.Category.SubCategories,
              this.props.Category.CategoryId
            )}
          >
            <div>
              <h5>{this.props.Category.CategoryName}</h5>
            </div>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CategoryComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavLink      
  className="block"
  to={this.props.OnUpdateSubCategories(
     this.props.Category.SubCategories,
   this.props.Category.CategoryId
 )}
>
```

when you put a function call inside props, it will be called everytime when `render()` runs

you can use arrow functions in props

```
to={
()=>{this.props.OnUpdateSubCategories(
     this.props.Category.SubCategories,
   this.props.Category.CategoryId
 )}
}
```

but a function instance will be created in every render

so it is better to create a function inside `CategoryComponent`

Comment: It works, i did lot of research and i didn't found any solutions. Thanks